# Cannot capture stdout/stderr in Perl on Windows using pipes

Tags: perl, subprocess, pipe, ipc

I'm trying to write a function that spawns a subprocess, allows us to capture stdout and stderr separately, and returns it exit status. I know there are libraries for this, but let's make it a restriction to not use third party libraries, only built-in functions and language features (in the bigger problem scope, I do not have control over these restrictions, sorry).

I'm on Windows 10.0.18362 build 18362. I'm using ActiveState perl 5, version 28, subversion 1 (v5.28.1) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread.

Here's a minimal reproduction:

foo.pl

```perl
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

sub _autoflush {
    my ($fh, $val) = @_;
    my $prev = select $fh;
    $| = $val;
    select $prev;
}

sub _create_pipe {
    my ($overload_fh) = @_;
    my $fd = fileno($overload_fh);
    open(my $orig, ">&", $overload_fh) || die("failed to save fd $fd");
    pipe(my $rh, my $wh);
    _autoflush($rh, 1);
    _autoflush($wh, 1);
    open($overload_fh, ">&", $wh) || die("failed to dup fd $fd");
    close($wh);
    return ($rh, $orig);
}

sub _restore_handle {
    my ($overload_fh, $orig) = @_;
    my $fd = fileno($orig);
    open($overload_fh, ">&", $orig) || die("failed to restore fd $fd");
}

sub _capture_stream {
    my ($read_handle) = @_;
    my $cap;
    while (<$read_handle>) {
        s/\r\n/\n/g;
        $cap .= $_;
    }
    return $cap;
}

sub subprocess_run {
    my ($cmd) = @_;
    my ($rh1, $orig1) = _create_pipe(\*STDOUT);
    my ($rh2, $orig2) = _create_pipe(\*STDERR);

    my $exit_status = system($cmd);
    close(STDOUT);
    close(STDERR);

    my $stdout_capture = _capture_stream($rh1);
    my $stderr_capture = _capture_stream($rh2);

    _restore_handle(\*STDOUT, $orig1);
    _restore_handle(\*STDERR, $orig2);
    
    return ($stdout_capture, $stderr_capture, $exit_status);
}

my ($stdout, $stderr, $exit_status) = subprocess_run(qq(cmd /c "perl bar.pl"));
my @stdout = split /\n/, $stdout;
my @stderr = split /\n/, $stderr;
print(Dumper(\@stdout));
print(Dumper(\@stderr));
print(Dumper($exit_status >> 8));
```

bar.pl:

```perl
use strict;

for (1..125) {
    print "$_\n";
}
exit 1;
```

The above deadlocks, but if I change the range from `1..125` to `1..124` it works. The output I get with `1..124` is the expected output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '1',
          '2',
          '3',
          '4',
          '5',
          '6',
          '7',
          '8',
          '9',
          '10',
          '11',
          '12',
          '13',
          '14',
          '15',
          '16',
          '17',
          '18',
          '19',
          '20',
          '21',
          '22',
          '23',
          '24',
          '25',
          '26',
          '27',
          '28',
          '29',
          '30',
          '31',
          '32',
          '33',
          '34',
          '35',
          '36',
          '37',
          '38',
          '39',
          '40',
          '41',
          '42',
          '43',
          '44',
          '45',
          '46',
          '47',
          '48',
          '49',
          '50',
          '51',
          '52',
          '53',
          '54',
          '55',
          '56',
          '57',
          '58',
          '59',
          '60',
          '61',
          '62',
          '63',
          '64',
          '65',
          '66',
          '67',
          '68',
          '69',
          '70',
          '71',
          '72',
          '73',
          '74',
          '75',
          '76',
          '77',
          '78',
          '79',
          '80',
          '81',
          '82',
          '83',
          '84',
          '85',
          '86',
          '87',
          '88',
          '89',
          '90',
          '91',
          '92',
          '93',
          '94',
          '95',
          '96',
          '97',
          '98',
          '99',
          '100',
          '101',
          '102',
          '103',
          '104',
          '105',
          '106',
          '107',
          '108',
          '109',
          '110',
          '111',
          '112',
          '113',
          '114',
          '115',
          '116',
          '117',
          '118',
          '119',
          '120',
          '121',
          '122',
          '123',
          '124'
        ];
$VAR1 = [];
$VAR1 = 1;
```

I suppose a pipe is not being flushed even with autoflush on for the filehandle.

I've taken a peek at Capture::Tiny to see how they do it, and it looks like they write to temp files and then read it back into the parent process memory.

Any thoughts on how I could get the code to work with a range of `1..125`, on Windows, without using third party libraries, while using pipes, avoiding disk I/O? Or maybe this is all just not idiomatic in perl somehow (wouldn't be the first time I've gotten caught in that trap), either way, I'm open to correction within the aforementioned restrictions.

Comment: Here's the link to the reddit post in case more information is extended there: https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/o5bmef/cannot_capture_stdout_stderr_separately_in_perl/

Answer (score 0):

Pipes have limited size and if the data written to the write end of the buffer is too large, deadlock will occur.

Attempting to use `select(2)` (https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select#select-RBITS,WBITS,EBITS,TIMEOUT) for a polling implementation:

```perl
use strict;

sub main {
   vec(my $rin, fileno(STDIN),  1) = 1;
   my $nfound = select(my $rout = $rin, undef, my $eout = $rin, undef);
   print("nfound: $nfound\n");
   print("$!\n");
}

main();
```

results in

```
nfound: -1
An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.
```

It is probably much simpler to just use file I/O